# Software to batch extract what is reflected inside an image?

Tags: images, image-processing

I am looking for software or a program operate on a folder of image to extract what is in the background being reflected off of shiny surfaces contained within the image.

For example, can software remove the "Moe's Tavern Proudly Serves Duff Beer" from this image to reveal what is in the background?

[image]

Ideally it would be automatic but I realize that it may be tough for software to know which is the reflection and which is the foreground.